# Project folders data can not be uploaded when publish on server in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, publish

I have a folder called GalleryImg, the user can upload images dynamically, which is stored in this folder. But when I publish the project on real server then this folder can not be uploaded. I have attached the image of this folder below -

[image]

As you can see this folder contains many images but it does not shows any images here. please help me about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If folder is empty, it will not be published. So you can put a placeholder.txt file with build action set to "Content" inside this folder to force publish.

Comment: The folder is not empty, it has multiple image files.

Comment: Could you please explain in webforms